# Fail to install cmdstanr

Tags: r

I am new to R. My intention is to install the “rethinking” package according to the website: https://github.com/rmcelreath/rethinking

I have already installed the rstan package but fail to install the cmdstanr package according to :https://mc-stan.org/cmdstanr/ .

My environment is as follows

Windows 7
R 4.0.5 ( i tried 4.1.2 which also failed so now tried another version)
RStudio 2022.02.0+443 “Prairie Trillium” Release
I run

```
install.packages(“cmdstanr”, repos = c(“Repository for distributing (some) stan-dev R packages | r-packages”, getOption(“repos”)))
```

and it failed with this error

```
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository https://mc-stan.org/r-packages/src/contrib:
cannot open URL ‘https://mc-stan.org/r-packages/src/contrib/PACKAGES%E2%80%99
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘cmdstanr’ is not available for this version of R
A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
R Installation and Administration
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository https://mc-stan.org/r-packages/bin/windows/contrib/4.1:
cannot open URL ‘https://mc-stan.org/r-packages/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/PACKAGES%E2%80%99
```

I then try

```
remotes::install_github("stan-dev/cmdstanr")
```

but it failed again with the following error.

```
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
invalid multibyte string, element 1
```

I somehow found from google that adding the following code may solve the problem so i tried.

```
Sys.setenv(LANG = "en_US.UTF-8")
remotes::install_github("stan-dev/cmdstanr")
```

And got the following errors.

```
Downloading GitHub repo stan-dev/cmdstanr@HEAD
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2bceh3\remotes30ac538d508c\stan-dev-cmdstanr-b62ad1f/DESCRIPTION' ... 
-  preparing 'cmdstanr': (929ms)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
   Error in parse(con, encoding = "UTF-8") : 
     invalid multibyte character in parser at line 4
   Execution halted
Error: Failed to install 'cmdstanr' from GitHub:
  System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed, exit status: 1, stdout & stderr were printed
```

I have tried to search for solution in google and this forum but fail to find any that works for me. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to follow the instructions on mc-stan.org: https://mc-stan.org/cmdstanr/articles/cmdstanr.html

```
install.packages("cmdstanr", repos = c("https://mc-stan.org/r-packages/", getOption("repos")))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first like to confirm that if your computer is leased by an institute or an organisation and therfore you are not the administrator, if yes, then you need to check the library path and manually adapt it to your approachable library path that you have access to.